# Media Queries in Bootstrap Do Nothing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm trying to set up a media query where the border changes for a specific div from right in all sizes above xs and bottom for xs. I can't however seem to get media queries to do anything at all.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with Wordpress.

I've got this line in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

And then this in CSS:

```
#second-post {
color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #second-post {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

So the color of text should change to red by never does. I've tried changing the @media selector to (min-width: 200px) so it would activate on my desktop but still nothing.

Does anyone have an idea as to why the media query is just being totally ignored?

Comment: Try loading your css file after the bootstrap's css file.

Comment: I'm importing bootstrap's css at the top of my own style.css, the media query is at the bottom of this file.

Answer (score 0):

Check that there are no unwanted spaces in your code.